# How to use JFileChooser.showOpenDialog to open a specific file?

Tags: java, jfilechooser

Right now I am able to open a up any file that I want, however the default file that opens up is My Documents. How can I set the default path to a file that is saved in my java project?

Right now this is what I have:

```
              try{
                  int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(MyPanel.this);//Chooser is my JFileChooser
                    if(option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                       //do stuff
                    }
              }catch(Exception ex){}
```

What do I have to pass into `showOptionDialog()` to open a folder if it is **located in my java project**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JFileChooser change default directory in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516829/jfilechooser-change-default-directory-in-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("desired_current_directory");
```

or

```
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("desired_current_directory"));
```

If you want to open `My Pics` folder under your project directory use

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("./My Pics");
```

Comment: cool that works! thanks! Is there another way to read that file without giving the full path name? The reason why I ask this is because if I where to give this project to someone and have it run on their computer, the path for them would not be the same. How can I get it to read from a folder, lets say named "My Pics", if it is saved in my java project?

Answer (score 2):

You can either add directory to the constructor of [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) like this:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser("directory");
```

or you can set the current directory using `setCurrentDirectory(File dir)`:

```
fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("directory"));
```

It is probably easier to just set it with the constructor, but if you need to change it after creating the JFileChooser, use `setCurrentDirectory(File dir)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add directory to the constructor of JFileChooser like this:

```
 JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("put here your directory"));
    int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(getParent());
    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
    {
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        jTextField.setText(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```